# Enumeration values for FaxJob.SetStatus method

Tags: c#, com

Using Windows Fax Service, I am trying to cancel a fax from the Windows Fax Console. According to this [worthless documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I need to pass in a value `JC_Delete` which appears that it is some enumeration, however, the documentation fails to leave out what it is or how to get it.

I found another [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) stating in the last sentence that these `JC` values are just constants which the user defines. Finally, I found a [forum post](http://www.oasq.com/Cancelling-fax-job-thread-228762-1-1.html) stating that it's just an enumeration in a C++ header file and the Microsoft guy showed the enumeration consisting of:

`JC_UNKNOWN = 0
JC_DELETE = 1
JC_PAUSE = 2
JC_RESUME = 3
JC_RESTART = JC_RESUME`

I just tried plugging in numbers, 0 or 1 since the method calls for an int and then I receive an exception

**COM error:
the handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))**

Here is my bit of code. I am able to get the FaxJob object just fine. It's just calling the SetStatus() method that bombs.

```
    var job = this.getFaxJobsInQueue().Where(j => j.JobId == JobId).Single();
    job.SetStatus(1);
```

Comment: Just realised my answer is what you've already tried. What bombs? Do you have an exception?

Comment: Simon, I updated my answer and put the exception in bold. It is thrown when I just plug in a int, like 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arg!! Found the problem! It was very simple! I forgot to connect to the fax console. Apparently that is what `the handle is invalid` was indicating.  My problem was in the method that returned all the jobs connected and disconnected. Once I had the FaxJob object, I was suppose to connect again.  Here is my updated code:

```
        var job = this.getFaxJobsInQueue().Where(j => j.JobId == JobId).Single();
        this.objFaxServer.Connect(faxServerConnectionString);
        job.SetStatus(1);
        this.objFaxServer.Disconnect();
```